# xcodebuild import XLIFF localization

Tags: import, localization, xcode6, xcodebuild

I just discovered, that Xcode 6's command line tool allows you to export XLIFF localization files using

```
xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath
```

Now I'd like to export XLIFF on my CI when pushing to a GIT repo. This would be fairly easy.

But, pre-build I'd need to import them again. Unfortunately `xcodebuild` doesn't provide a `-importLocalizations` or similar.

Is there any other way to import XLIFF using the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
xcodebuild -importLocalizations -localizationPath <dirpath> -project <projectname> [-forceImport]
```

Comment: `xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-importLocalizations'`

Comment: Has `-importLocalizations` been added to `xcodebuild` yet?

Comment: there is no such option in up-to-date version of `xcodebuild`

Comment: Time to celebrate! As azlan answered, the newest Xcode – 7.1.1 – contains this feature. As well `xcodebuild` as the Xcode GUI now offer import.

Answer (score 1):

`xcodebuild` 7.1.1 has this option.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10235209)

Comment: Even though @ForceMagic is absolutely right, this answer is correct. So Please make your answer more of an answer and I'm willing to accept ;) Post some references and complete sentences as well. Best would be an example.